# mod_rewrite not working for me

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, fedora, wordpress

mod_rewrite is not working for my wordpress install on fedora. The module is loading, and AllowOveride is set to All in httpd.conf.

Ive restarted apache, and restarted the machine also incase that worked. Im totally lost.

here is  my .htaccess file

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
Allowoverride FileInfo

# to protect thisfile
<Files ~ "^\.htaccess">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# to protect wp-config.php
<Files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks

Comment: have you checked the logs?

Comment: apache logs? it just says file not found.

Comment: RewriteLog RewriteLogLevel are your friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File not found? Which file, wp-config.php? IS the wp-config.php in the same directory as the .htaccess?

Comment: no, all wordpress permlinks that im trying to access come back file not found. wp-config is there, and the entry in the .htaccess is just to hide it from robots.

Comment: I removed 
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
Allowoverride FileInfo

as those were causing a 500 error on my server. Other than that I copied your script aside from the BEGIN wordpress section, as I already had that, pasted it into a wordpress install on one of my machines, and tried to access wp-config.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /techtalk/wp-config.php on this server.

So it works for me, other than the first two lines.